# Creating Random Alpha numeric on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm java programmer that 'must' move on to obj-C for a while,

i got some confuse when  generating random alphanumeric code... here my javacode:

PS: i want to generate code like this :Gh12PU67, AC88pP13, Bk81gH89

```
private String generateCode(){
 String code = "";
 Random r = new Random();
 char[] c = new char[]{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

 for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
  int uplow = r.nextInt(2);
  String temp = ""+ c[r.nextInt(c.length)];
  if(uplow==1)
   code = code + temp.toUpperCase();
 else
   code = code + temp;

 if((i+1)%2==0){
   code += r.nextInt(10);
   code += r.nextInt(10);
 }
}

return code;
}
```

then i create on OBJ-C

```
-(void)generateCode{
    NSString *alphabet  = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789";
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:4];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 4; i++) {
        u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
        unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];

    }
    NSLog(@"s-->%@",s);
}
```

but i got "HpNz" for result AC88pP13 insted that hve pattern String,string, numeric,numeric, lowescase string,numeric,numeric...

that case screw my life for 3 days...

Comment: First, you'll need to go from 0 to 8 if you want 8 characters. Then, use a separate alphabet for each part of the string.

Comment: hi @H2CO3 can you help me fix that code? i'm totally newbie and noobs on this language :(

Comment: Your code has the right structure but you haven't tried to duplicate the logic. That isn't a language issue you've just not done a full mapping.

Comment: You may want to generate UUID: `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString])` This will not match your pattern but this is `more random` alphanum sequence

Comment: @PetroKorienev noted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Objective-C code looks good, but (as @Wain correctly said in a comment above),
the Java function function contains logic to insert 2 digits after 2 letters, which you
have not replicated in the Objective-C method.

I would make that logic slightly less obscure and write it as

```
- (void)generateCode
{
    static NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY";
    static NSString *digits = @"0123456789";
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:8];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        uint32_t r;

        // Append 2 random letters:
        r = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)[letters length]);
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", [letters characterAtIndex:r]];
        r = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)[letters length]);
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", [letters characterAtIndex:r]];

        // Append 2 random digits:
        r = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)[digits length]);
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", [digits characterAtIndex:r]];
        r = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)[digits length]);
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", [digits characterAtIndex:r]];

    }
    NSLog(@"s-->%@",s);
}
```

*Remark* (from the man page):
`arc4random_uniform(length)` is preferred over `arc4random() % length`,
as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

*Remark:* A more verbatim translation of the Java code `code += r.nextInt(10);`
to Objective-C would be

```
r = arc4random_uniform(10);
[s appendString:[@(r) stringValue]];
```

which creates a `NSNumber` object `@(r)` from the random number, and then
converts that to a string.

Comment: so in obj-C have 2 method between string random and numeric random?

Comment: @YAZID: I do not understand the question. It is the same method. letters are selected randomly from the `letters` string, and digits are selected randomly from the `digits` string.

Comment: @YAZID: As I understand it, the Java code `code += r.nextInt(10)` computes a random integer 0..9, and *implicitly converts* that to a character and appends it to the string. You *could* do similarly in Objective-C, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: yeap.. your code running,, hahha yeah man,, its not easy as java :)... but thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want a secure random string you should use this code:

```
#define ASCII_START_NUMERS 0x30
#define ASCII_END_NUMERS 0x39

#define ASCII_START_LETTERS_A 0x41
#define ASCII_END_LETTERS_Z 0x5A

#define ASCII_START_LETTERS_a 0x61
#define ASCII_END_LETTERS_z 0x5A

-(NSString *)getRandomString:(int)length {
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    while (result.length != length) {
        NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:1];
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, [data mutableBytes]);
        Byte currentChar = 0;
        [data getBytes:&currentChar length:1];
        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (currentChar > ASCII_START_NUMERS && currentChar < ASCII_END_NUMERS) { // 0 to 0
            [result appendString:s];
            continue;
        }
        if (currentChar > ASCII_START_LETTERS_A && currentChar < ASCII_END_LETTERS_Z) { // A to Z
            [result appendString:s];
            continue;
        }
        if (currentChar > ASCII_START_LETTERS_a && currentChar < ASCII_END_LETTERS_z) { // a to z
            [result appendString:s];
            continue;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```